# How to use the default value in Terraform when the corresponding environment variable exists?

Tags: terraform

I have a TF variable:

```
variable "test" {
  type = number
  default = 1
}
```

I want Terraform to use the specified default value `1` when I pass the `TF_VAR_test` variable with an empty value.

Trying this way

```
TF_VAR_test= terraform plan
```

fails with

```
│ Error: Invalid value for input variable
│ 
│ The environment variable TF_VAR_test does not contain a valid
│ value for variable "test": a number is required.
```

How can I use the default value if the environment variable exists and is empty?

Answer (score 1):

In that case you can't use a type. Empty `string` is not a `number`. Instead, you can do the following:

```
variable "test" {
  default = 1
  validation {
      condition =  var.test != "" && can(tonumber(var.test))
      error_message = "Only number of emptry string are accepted."
  }
}

locals {
    test_value = coalesce(tonumber(var.test), 1)
}
```

And then you use `local.test_value` later on.

Answer (score 0):

use local and if statement

```
variable "test" {
  type    = string
  default = "defaultValue"
}
locals {
  test = var.test != "" ? var.test : "defaultValue"
}

output "name" {
  value = local.test
}
```